# passing const this to function accepting const pointer is not const-correct?

Tags: c++, pointers, compiler-errors, constants

I have a class template `Foo` with the following member function:

```
bool contains(const T& item) const
```

I have instantiated this with a pointer type: `Foo<Bar*>`, leading me to expect that the member function will now have the following signature:

```
bool contains(const Bar*& item) const
```

In a `const` `Bar` member function, I attempt to pass `this` to `Foo<Bar*>::contains`:

```
bool Bar::func(const Foo<Bar*>& foo) const
{
    return foo.contains(this);
}
```

This fails to compile, with the following error:

> error: invalid conversion from ‘`const Bar*`’ to ‘`Bar*`’

**Question:**

- Why is my `const T&` parameter not const-correct?
- What signature for `Foo<T>::contains(...) const` is required to allow calling with `this` to compile?

**Full example:**

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename T>
struct Foo
{
    bool contains(const T& item) const
    {
        return false;
    }
};

struct Bar
{
    bool func(const Foo<Bar*>& foo) const
    {
        return foo.contains(this);
    }
};
```

**Error output:**

```
scratch/main.cpp:17:33: error: invalid conversion from ‘const Bar*’ to ‘Bar*’ [-fpermissive]
         return foo.contains(this);
                                 ^
scratch/main.cpp:7:10: note: initializing argument 1 of ‘bool Foo<T>::contains(const T&) const [with T = Bar*]’
     bool contains(const T& item) const
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I have instantiated this with a pointer type: `Foo<Bar*>`, leading me
>   to expect that the member function will now have the following
>   signature:
>
> ```
> bool contains(const Bar*& item) const
> ```

That's where the problem is. When `T = Bar*`, the expression

```
bool contains(const T& item) const
```

Will actually compile to

```
bool contains(Bar * const & item) const
```

That is, a reference-to-a-const-pointer-to-Bar.
It makes sense of you think about it: you want T to be const, and then you want a reference to that.

If you want to apply the const in the usual "intended" way (though this might cause some surprises for seasoned C++ programmers), you can declare your container and member function in the following way:

```
template <class T>
class Container {
public:
    using const_bare_type = typename std::conditional<
        std::is_pointer<T>::value,
        typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type const*,
        const T>::type;

    bool contains(const const_bare_type& item);
};
```

Comment: Am I able to make any changes to my `Foo` member function in order to allow me to pass `this` to it?

Comment: @SteveLorimer No, error occures when instantiating `Foo<Bar*>`, see my answer.

Comment: @YamMarcovic It looks like some cheating ;-)

Comment: @YamMarcovic well I wan't my `Foo` class to work for pointer types *and* non-pointer types. So it should just take a `const ref to T` in the signature - will I need to have 2 overloads and use SFINAE with `enable_if` on pointer types to get that to work?

Comment: @SteveLorimer Kind of. You don't necessarily need to have 2 overloads. In the class definition, you can use some traits to define a `const_bare_type`, which would yield `const T` for non-pointer types, and `const T*` for pointer types. Then declare `contains(const_bare_type& item)`.

Comment: @SteveLorimer I added some sample code for that last bit, and removed the overly-specialized pointer stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler alerts about wrong line, you must write:

```
bool func(const Foo<const Bar*>& foo) const
```

I.e. `const Bar*` in template parameter, because `Bar::func` receives `const Bar * this` as its parameter, and cannot convert it to `Bar*` in template parameter (cannot remove `const`).

Comment: I don't believe I can change a `Foo<Bar*>` to a `Foo<const Bar*>` can I?

Comment: [The compiler sees foo<T> and foo<const T> as two completely different and unrelated types](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2290590/955273)